# How do I serialise a base class from a derived class?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a class, call it `A`, that I want to serialise.

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive&, const unsigned int);
};
```

However, the class itself is actually instantiated as a derived class, call it `B`.

```
class B : public A
{
};
```

Class `B` doesn't contain any interesting information that I want to serialise, so I really just want to serialise A (and deserialises to A - I don't care about B). This compiles, but when I run the code I see this exception:

```
Writing output state to out.xml
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
  what():  unregistered class - derived class not registered or exported
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: Make class B serializable, whose only contents is its superclass.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html#export